# What is relationship between Google API Discovery Service and My Web Service API Implemented with 3rd Party WS Framework Deployed on GAE

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework

I deployed Web Service API implemented with 3rd party Web service Framework, such as REST Framework (Python), into GAE. The API look like this:

```
https://hello.appspot.com/api_my/api/v1/hello
```

I want to consume this web service API from a python client from another web server deployed somewhere. According to Google API client document/sample, I will end up using something like:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build


service = serviceName,  
            version, 
            http=None, 
            discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI, 
            developerKey=None, 
            model=None, 
            requestBuilder=HttpRequest, 
            credentials=None, 
            cache_discovery=True, 
            cache=None)
```

My questions:

1) How to discover the API: https://hello.appspot.com/api_my/api/v1/hello

2) I did not implement any discovery service in the GAE hosing https://hello.appspot.com/api_my/api/v1/hello. Do I need to add discovery service (what extra I need to add besides my web service code)? Or if deployed on GAE, somehow GAE will find it?

Can someone explain? Sample code if possible.

BTW, I am planning to use service account, or API key, and created those keys on GAE.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything with this, so take this comment with a huge grain of salt -- But, If you are using the cloud endpoints API on GAE, IIRC, the discovery ends up getting baked in and you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: Thank you. if implementing google endpoint api (I think it's rpc) to provide same service, the implementation will take care of service discovery on my server (my understanding). But, I am not using any google framework to create web service. In this case, what is the 'service'? All I know if my API. I feel really confused.